# Auto-size data-grid of react-grid-layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using responsive react grid layout in a container where i have expandable/collapsible side bar. As of now when RGL is getting loaded with all its data-grid items, it looks perfect however when i expand/collapse sidebar (which changes the parent div size of the RGL), RGL items doesn't get resized automatically. its works perfect with window resize however not with container size change.
I have tried modifying height/width pragmatically which works then placeholder and drag/drop starts failing

Anyone have a quick solution for this

Comment: hey, any solution? I am looking answer for the same question